# Not rendering properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, render-passes

[image]

hello. I am new to blender. I created this donut. I applied a creamy material to the donut. But in rendering it is not rendering correctly and the donut material is white+light blue instead of cream. Why is this?

Comment: Is it possible you have another (donut) object in the same location, but hidden? Objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders.

Comment: since you gave us no screenshots of your settings/outliner....and since you are a beginner so you won't really know which screenshot to provide - i would recommend to provide your blend file. Use this link https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions